# Locating Carnarton in ecclesiastical district of Tuckingmill in parish of Illogan, Cornwall?

Tags: england, cornwall, historical-gazetteer, 1840s, 1850s

My 2nd great grandmother Grace Martin Wills was born on 8 Feb 1849 at Carnarton and christened on 8 Apr 1849 at Tuckingmill which is between Camborne and Illogan in Cornwall.  Her father George was a Labourer.

In the 1851 Census their household was enumerated at Carnarton (in the ecclesiastical district of Tuckingmill, in the parish of Illogan) with her father George's occupation given as Rail Labourer.

I have not been able to locate Carnarton but at http://www.old-maps.co.uk/ I searched for Tuckingmill and not far to its south east, I located Carn Arthen and other place names like Carnarthen Farm.

Would this be the same location?

Comment: http://members.ozemail.com.au/~peterpjw/Carnarthen.html (scroll down to discussion of places) suggests you've identified the right place but is not sourced. I suspect it's an result of pronounciation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by @ColeValleyGirl, it appears that I have identified the correct location based on a post at http://members.ozemail.com.au/~peterpjw/Carnarthen.html

> Carnarthen - a locality, about half way between Camborne and Redruth,
>   in the parish of Illogan. It is surrounded by Brea, Bosleake, Piece,
>   Carnkie, Treskillard, Higher Condurrow, Pengegon and Tuckingmill. It
>   lies in the tin and copper mining region of the parish. Carnarthen was
>   the name of a farm at this location. Sometimes rendered Carn Arthen or
>   Carnarton. Records also refer to Carnarthen Moor. Click [here](http://members.ozemail.com.au/~peterpjw/Carnarthen.jpg) for a map
>   of the area around Carnarthen Farm circa 1888.